# How to install sqlite3 for python3.7 in seperate directory on linux without sudo commands?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, sqlite

I have the problem that when I run my code on a linux server I get:

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'**

So after researching, I found out sqlite3 was supposed to have been installed when I installed python, however it didn't. 
I think the problem comes from the way I installed python. Since I do not have sudo permissions, I installed python3.7 in a local directory using: [This guide](http://www.benhepworth.com/blog/2016/05/18/install-python-to-separate-directory-on-linux-in-5-easy-steps/). 
All solutions to this sqlite3 problem that I can find requires sudo commands.

Is there another way that I can install python3.7 together with sqlite3 in my local Linux directory without using any sudo commands?

I hope I have stated my question clearly and I would appreciate all the help I can get. Thank you!

Comment: what is this `my code` you are running? can you share? have you tried: `sudo apt install libsqlite3-dev`

Comment: I don't think the code is really important. The problem is that I don't have sqlite3 module. My code uses the openmdao module which happens to use the sqlite3 module.

Comment: try: `pip install pysqlite`

Comment: I did try that, installing pysqlite works, but I still get the same error message: No module named '_sqlite3'

Comment: can you download using `wget` and then `make install`?

Comment: I tried that, following this [link](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/install-sqlite3). However the final command `make install` doesn't work:

**/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6': Permission denied**

So is there a way how to do this is a more local directory which I have access to?

Comment: try this one. people says it works: `apt-get install libsqlite3-dev` or `apt-get install sqlite-devel`. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Actually I figured out how to get the `make install` to work. So I have sqlite3 now and it works. However, how do I get it to work with python? Should I re-install python now? And must the files of sqlite be in a specific location?

Comment: if you do `import sqlite3` in python what does it say?

Comment: `from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
File "/home/jriessbacher/python32/lib/python3.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'`
Those are the last lines

Answer (score 1):

While installing a python package in a Linux system without "sudo" privileges you can use 
For Python 3

 `pip3 install --user pysqlite3`


You can install any third party packages with the same method 

`pip3 install --user PACKAGE_NAME`

The `--user` flag to pip install tells Pip to install packages in some specific directories within your home directory. For more information [click here](https://matthew-brett.github.io/pydagogue/installing_on_debian.html).

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to first build sqlite3 into a user directory and then build python using that directory's libraries and include headers. In particular, @Ski has [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8657514/1190430) a similar question regarding python 2, which can be adopted to python 3:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/applications/src
$ cd ~/applications/src
$ # Download and build sqlite 3 (you might want to get a newer version)
$ wget http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-autoconf-3070900.tar.gz
$ tar xvvf sqlite-autoconf-3070900.tar.gz
$ cd sqlite-autoconf-3070900
$ ./configure --prefix=~/applications
$ make
$ make install

$ # Now download and build python 2, same works for python 3
$ cd ~/applications/src
$ wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.5.2/Python-2.5.2.tgz
$ tar xvvf Python-2.5.2.tgz
$ cd Python-2.5.2
$ ./configure --prefix=~/applications
$ make
$ make install

$ ~/applications/bin/python
```

Alternatively, if you already have to specify a different `--prefix` for some reason (this has happened to me with `pyenv`), use `LDFLAGS` and `CPPFLAGS` when configuring python build:

```
$ ./configure LDFLAGS=-L/home/user/applications/lib/ CPPFLAGS=-I/home/user/applications/include/
```